# Phonegap : BluetoothChatExample [Android]

Tags: java, android, cordova, bluetooth

I try to develop a minimalistic BluetoothChat for Android with Phonegap. The Plugin is based on the Android SDK Example of the BluetoothChat as you can see in the example code.

The native BluetoothChat works fine. 
The Problem is, when i call my "write"-Function, the "ConnectedThread" is always null, although the connection is established.

I can't recognize where it is set to null again, after the State was set to 3 (STATE_CONNECTED).

So when i run the program native on android, it works fine and the state during write is always 3, but when i use my phonegap plugin 'r'(ConnectedThread) becomes null :

```
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
       Log.i(TAG, "State "+mState);
       if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected Thread "+mConnectedThread);
        r = mConnectedThread;

    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}
```

I used a lot of debug messages, but i was never informed that the state is null again.

Full source code :

**PLUGIN.java**

```
public class BluetoothConnection extends CordovaPlugin {

    //Android specific tag-messages
    private static final String TAG ="BluetoothConnection";
    private static final boolean D = true;


    // Member-Variables

    public BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    public JSONArray mListOfDiscoveredDevices;
    public String mConnectedDeviceName;
    public ConnectionHandler mConnectionHandler;



    // Phonegap-specific actions, which call the function
    public String ACTION_ENABLEBLUETOOTH = "enableBluetooth";
    public String ACTION_DISABLEBLUETOOTH = "disableBluetooth";
    public String ACTION_DISCOVERDECIVES = "discoverDevices";
    public String ACTION_STOPDISCOVERDEVICES = "stopDiscoverDevices";
    public String ACTION_CREATEBOND = "createBond";
    public String ACTION_WRITEMESSAGE = "writeMessage";

    // not usable, this moment
    public String ACTION_DISCONNECT = "disconnect";

    //Message types sent from the ConnectionHandler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
public static final String TOAST = "toast";



    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
                    CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            if (mBluetoothAdapter.equals(null)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "no adapter was found");
            }

            mConnectionHandler = new ConnectionHandler(mHandler);


            if (action.equals(ACTION_ENABLEBLUETOOTH)) {
                    enableBluetooth();
            }
            else if (action.equals(ACTION_DISABLEBLUETOOTH)) {
                    disableBluetooth();
            }
            else if (action.equals(ACTION_DISCOVERDECIVES)) {
                    discoverDevices();
            }
            else if (action.equals(ACTION_STOPDISCOVERDEVICES)) {
                    stopDiscovering(callbackContext);
            }
            else if (action.equals(ACTION_CREATEBOND)) {
                    try {
                            BluetoothDevice remoteBtDevice = createBond(args, callbackContext);
                            connect(remoteBtDevice, callbackContext);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            else if(action.equals(ACTION_WRITEMESSAGE)){
                    writeMessage(args.getString(0));
            }

            else if (action.equals(ACTION_DISCONNECT)) {
                    disconnect();
            }

            return false;

    }





    public void enableBluetooth() {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.equals(null)) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
                    Log.i(TAG, "bluetooth on");
            }

    }

    public void disableBluetooth() {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    Log.i(TAG, "bluetooth off");
            }
    }

    public void discoverDevices() {
            mListOfDiscoveredDevices = new JSONArray();
            Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(mFoundDevices, intentFilter);
            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private void stopDiscovering(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }

            PluginResult res = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK,
                            mListOfDiscoveredDevices);
            res.setKeepCallback(true);
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(res);

            Log.i("Info", "Stopped discovering Devices !");

    }


    public BluetoothDevice createBond(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws Exception {
            String macAddress = args.getString(0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connect to MacAddress "+macAddress);
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
            Log.i("Device","Device "+btDevice);

            Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
    Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");
    Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);

    if(btDevice.equals(null))
            throw new NullPointerException("Remote BluetoothDevice could not be paired !");

    return btDevice;
}

    public void removeBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice) throws Exception {
             Class btClass = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
     Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");
     Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
    }



    public void connect(BluetoothDevice btDevice, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
            if(!btDevice.equals(null)){
                    mConnectionHandler.connect(btDevice, false);
                    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
                    result.setKeepCallback(true);
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);

                    Log.i(TAG, "Status after connecting "+mConnectionHandler.getState());
            }
            else {
                    callbackContext.error("Could not connect to "+btDevice.getAddress());
            }
    }


    public void disconnect(){

    }

    public void writeMessage(String message){
            if(mConnectionHandler.getState() != ConnectionHandler.STATE_CONNECTED){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Could not write to device");
                    Log.i(TAG, "State "+mConnectionHandler.getState());
            }

            if(message.length() > 0) {
                    byte[] send = message.getBytes();
                    mConnectionHandler.write(send);

                    Log.i(TAG, "sending "+message);

            }
            else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "There is nothing to send.");
            }
    }



    private BroadcastReceiver mFoundDevices = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "found Device !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);


                            Log.i("FOUND", "Name " + device.getName() + "-" + device.getAddress());
                            JSONObject discoveredDevice = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                    discoveredDevice.put("name", device.getName());
                                    discoveredDevice.put("adress", device.getAddress());
                                    if (!isJSONInArray(discoveredDevice)) {
                                            mListOfDiscoveredDevices.put(discoveredDevice);
                                    }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }

            }
    };




    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {

        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);

            switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case ConnectionHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionHandler.STATE_CONNECTED !");
                            break;
                    case ConnectionHandler.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionHandler.STATE_CONNECTING !");
                            break;
                    case ConnectionHandler.STATE_LISTEN:
                            Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionHandler.STATE_LISTEN !");
                            break;
                    case ConnectionHandler.STATE_NONE:
                            Log.i(TAG, "ConnectionHandler.STATE_NONE !");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                        byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                        // construct a string from the buffer
                        String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Write "+writeMessage);
                        break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                        // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                        String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Read "+readMessage);
                        break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                        // save the connected device's name
                        mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                        Log.i(TAG, mConnectedDeviceName);
                        break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                        String message = msg.getData().getString(TOAST);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost : " +message);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };}
```

**CONNECTION-HANDLER**

```
public class ConnectionHandler {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
private static final boolean D = true;

// Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

// Unique UUID for this application
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
    UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
    UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// Member fields
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private final Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0; // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; // now connected to a remote device

public ConnectionHandler(Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}


private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothConnection.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}


public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

public synchronized void start() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
        mSecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
        mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
}


public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}


public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
        device, final String socketType) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothConnection.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(BluetoothConnection.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
       Log.i(TAG, "State "+mState);
       if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected Thread "+mConnectedThread);
        r = mConnectedThread;

    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}


private void connectionFailed() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothConnection.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(BluetoothConnection.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    ConnectionHandler.this.start();
}

private void connectionLost() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothConnection.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(BluetoothConnection.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    ConnectionHandler.this.start();
}

private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    private String mSocketType;

    public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                    MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (ConnectionHandler.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                mSocketType);
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}



private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private String mSocketType;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
        setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (ConnectionHandler.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothConnection.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                ConnectionHandler.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothConnection.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}}
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Hi, belafarinrod i am new to phonegap and have some issue similar to yours. I can find nearest bluetooth devices but couldn't able to send any message to another bluetooth device, can u send ur source code to my mail so i could get some idea. mail ID: s.sarann7@gmail.com.. thanks

Comment: Hey Saran, no need - it's on github : https://github.com/belafarinrod91/DHBWOBD2VehicleDiagnosis

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for providing source code it was very helpful to learn. Is it possible to send a test file which is currently present in sdcard to another device. if so can u please share it, that would be great-full.

Comment: What do you mean with a test file ? This chat only for string communication and not for objects. You have to look up this somewhere else, for example : http://www.kpbird.com/2011/04/android-send-image-via-bluetooth.html

Comment: Sorry it is text file only. how to send text file from one device to another device via bluetooth using phonegap. i have searched for lot more bluetooth plugins to send file but i couldn't get one.

Comment: Well there are multiple approaches : If you want to use my code (which is simply the android bluetooth chat example) parse the text-file on the one phone send the content via bluetooth and finally create a new text file on the other phone. Another approach would be to use the link, I already showed you above. You already have the bluetooth connection, just add the function for send an object, instead of write. !!! Attention : My code connects to a serial Device, if you want to another android phone, use the UUID from the SDK Example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented again in a new project - now it works, don't know why - but it work now.